# Return Max from Group By ( Another Column)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to find the formula that returns the Max Column from my sample.

[image: Sample]

I tried with MAX(IF( ... but i cannot make it returns the max of each group.

I tried this one : =MAX(IF(A:A=A3;B:B))  not working

Comment: What is the exact formula you tried and did you confirm it with Ctrl+Shift+Enter?

Comment: I Tried this one and it's not working

=MAX(IF(A:A=A3;B:B))

Comment: Did you confirm it with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`? It is an array formula.

Comment: yes, but it does not return correctly

Comment: Can't reproduce (well assuming you used `A2` instead of `A3` based on your screenshot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following in C2 and copy down.

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,$B$2:$B$9/(A2=$A$2:$A$9),1)
```

AGGREGATE will perform an array operation with formula 14 with out the need to have it entered as an array formula.  As a result try and avoid using full column references within the formula and instead keep it to you data to avoid excess calculations.

[image: poc]